# Error when trying to hide a page post

Tags: post, hide, facebook-page

I'm trying to hide a page post by setting is_hidden to true.  I'm POSTing to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[post ID]?is_hidden=true&access_token=[page access token]
```

I get this error message:

```
(#100) Cannot hide/unhide story posted by post itself
```

What exactly is it trying to tell me?  I can hide the post using Facebook's GUI, so I know it can be hidden.  Does anyone have a working example of hiding a page post?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that I was using the wrong field. Instead of is_hidden, I needed to use timeline_visibility to solve this problem.

If you set timeline_visibility to "hidden", the post won't appear in the page's timeline. It still appears in newsfeeds, which is the behavior I want.

Also, it doesn't appear to work if I set the timeline visibility at the same time that I publish the post. It has to be set after the post is published.

I couldn't find the timeline_visibility field in Facebook's documentation, so I don't know if it's supported or not.

Comment: Question: if timeline_visibility field isn't in Facebook's documentation, how did you find out about it?

Comment: It's been a long time, but I think I found that field in a response object from Facebook when I was testing my client.